# How to pass parameter to a template of a subnode?

Tags: xslt, position

My XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <do>
    <img attr1="test">
      <subnode attr1="test">
        <text>THIS</text>
      </subnode>
    <img>
    <other />
    <text />
  <do>
  <do>
    <text />
  <do>
  <text />
</root>
```

I would like to insert the number of do-Element I'm staying in to the Text node inside img/subnode. So far, I do have this piece of XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="do">
      <xsl:call-template name="alter-pos">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="position()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="alter-pos">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <!-- How to copy everything and alter Text? -->
  </xsl:template>
```

How can I copy all the elements while keep the variable count around in order to replace the Text content? I tried it with apply template, but then text of other depths are altered too... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `call-template` is usually a bad idea, and also what do you want your output XML to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably better to do this using standard pattern matching with an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

The key things to remember is that `position()` only works on the current node, but I found an [article that has an alternative](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asanto/archive/2004/09/08/226663.aspx).

The important part is defining a correct template for the text nodes you want to change like so:

```
  <xsl:template match="img/subnode/text/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::do[1]/preceding-sibling::do) + 1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here, we match only the `img/subnode/text/text()` node, then find the nearest `do` ancestor element - this may cause issues if `do`s are nested. Then, we count the number of previous `do` elements and output that number along with the text of the `img/subnode/text` node.

### In conclusion, this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="img/subnode/text/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::do[1]/preceding-sibling::do) + 1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Applied to this XML:

```
<root>
  <do>
    <img attr1="test">
      <subnode attr1="test">
        <text>THIS</text>
      </subnode>
      </img>
    <other />
    <text />
  </do>
  <do>
    <img attr1="test">
      <subnode attr1="test">
        <text>more tasks</text>
      </subnode>
      </img>
    <other />
    <text>A different task</text>
  </do>
  <do>
    <text />
  </do>
  <text />
</root>
```

### Gives this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <do>
        <img attr1="test">
            <subnode attr1="test">
                <text>1THIS</text>
            </subnode>
        </img>
        <other/>
        <text/>
    </do>
    <do>
        <img attr1="test">
            <subnode attr1="test">
                <text>2more tasks</text>
            </subnode>
        </img>
        <other/>
        <text>A different task</text>
    </do>
    <do>
        <text/>
    </do>
    <text/>
</root>
```

Comment: +1 for overriding the identity transform instead of using an `xsl:for-each`. However, you're stripping the `<text>` element itself (`1THIS` instead of `<text>1THIS</text>`). Also, it's much easier to use `xsl:number` than `count()` (just use `<xsl:number count="do"/>`).